# What are the limitations of AC coupling a MOSFET gate?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, nmos, pmos

I came up with this AC coupled half bridge for high positive and negative voltage output with logic level control that I cannot find in any resources about (probably due to wrong search terms):
[image: LTSpice schematic]
It seems to work very well in simulation as long as there is non-zero off time. Using diodes insted of resistors as in the one example I did find makes the operation mostly independent of duty cycle and improves startup.
Is there some issue I'm not seeing? What is the common name for this circuit?

Comment: Beware that the p-channel FET will tend to switch on as the supply rail comes up.  With diodes in parallel with R9 and R11 you should be able to make the switch-off faster than the switch-on and use a single control signal.

Comment: @Frog I did simulate that and diodes + bigger resistor work nicely, but I need three state output in this case. How to easiest solve the PMOS issue?

Comment: if you need to increase the dead time you could add capacitance in parallel with each gate-source.  If you need to achieve a DC tri-state then this could be possible with resistors in parallel with D2/D4.  You’d need to select component values carefully to get the desired characteristics as the control signal starts and stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitor-diode arrangement is a [diode clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_(electronics)). Leaving gates floating is dangerous if you  loose the input signals. A high-valued resistor between gate and source is recommended on each transistor. The clamp may take a few cycles in the beginning to settle down.
Be sure the driver sources can handle the current glitch when the high-voltage power supplies (VCC & VN) turn on.

I like to use transformer coupling to do the same thing since this gives better isolation. The following diagram is from International Rectifier AN950A.

[image: schematic]

Q1 is a low-power FET like a BS170. Q2 is the power FET. The diode is the body diode of Q1 which is a necessary component for this circuit to work. A capacitor between the gate and source may be necessary for long switching periods. A high value resistor between gate and source is probably a good idea (not mentioned in AN950A).